# Can't install Totem on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, totem

After upgrading to 12.04, not only has **totem** been uninstalled against my will and without my notice, but I cannot install it.

When I try to install it through the commandline, I get the following output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install totem
[sudo] password for <user>: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 totem : Depends: totem-common (= 3.0.1-0ubuntu21) but 3.2.2-0ubuntu1~oneiric1 is to be installed
         Recommends: totem-plugins but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: totem-mozilla but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this problem? As far as I can tell, I had no errors during the upgrade.

## Comment suggestions

Please post your suggestions as answers so I can give them followup individually.

### harisibrahimkv

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for <user>: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

### aking1012

`sudo apt-get update` fetches all the data and gives no errors.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Repeating the 3 commands above yields no different results.

```
$ dpkg-query -W totem-common totem-common3.0.1-0ubuntu21
totem-common    3.2.2-0ubuntu1~oneiric1
No packages found matching totem-common3.0.1-0ubuntu21.
```

Comment: Try running $sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: apt-get update.  apt-get upgrade.  apt-get dist-upgrade.  repeat until synced.  There is a totem-common for precise.  Something is out of sync

Comment: ~/$ dpkg-query -W totem-common
totem-common 3.0.1-0ubuntu21

Comment: I added the output of the commands you suggested to the question's body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you were using the GNOME3 Team which had a higher version of totem then available in precise. Assuming you don't want to continue to use that ppa in precise then, (also assumes the ppa is no longer enabled, you should check in Software Sources > Other Software

single command, copy & paste all

```
sudo apt-get purge totem-common && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install totem
```

Otherwise re-add the ppa for precise sources, update. Use of that ppa is somewhat at your own risk & certainly up to you to keep track of what's being installed ect

https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3

Comment: Very precise, Pangolin! I had that PPA on my sources and the upgrade had disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that totem is already installed, you will need only codecs try to run a video and it will install codecs automatically

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get purge totem && \ 
sudo apt-get build-dep totem && \
sudo apt-get install -f totem
```

Copy and paste all at once.